# Extracting Objects Based on Property Value in CodeIgniter/PHP

Tags: php, codeigniter, object, properties, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to retrieve all delegates from a `$delegates` object that have an 'event_id' that matches the current event id, which is stored in the variable `$current_event_id`.

That said, I've created a helper function to do the work, and I am including that function in my controller.

I've managed to get it to work to a certain extent, as in it displays the delegates I'm after, each in a list item but it also displays a blank list item for each of the delegates who's 'event_id' doesn't match the current event id.

Here's my code:

```
function total_delegate_info( $delegates, $current_event_id ) {
    $total_delegate_info = '<ul>';
    foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {
        $total_delegate_info .= '<li>';
        if(  $delegate->event_id == $current_event_id ) {
            $total_delegate_info .= $delegate->delegate_first_name . ' ' . $delegate->delegate_last_name;
        }
        $total_delegate_info .= '</li>';
    }
    $total_delegate_info .= '</ul>';
    return $total_delegate_info;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can improve this function? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly really but it was obviously because I was generating the list tags outside of my if statement. Doh!

```
    function total_delegate_info( $delegates, $current_event_id ) {

        $total_delegate_info = '<ul>';

            foreach ( $delegates as $delegate ) {


                    if( $delegate->event_id == $current_event_id ) {

                        $total_delegate_info .= '<li>';

                            $total_delegate_info .= $delegate->delegate_first_name . ' ' . $delegate->delegate_last_name;

                        $total_delegate_info .= '</li>';

                    }

            }
        $total_delegate_info .= '</ul>';

        return $total_delegate_info;

    }
```

Comment: Am I approaching this in the right way? Could this be refactored better?